# Two almost identical test class, one passed one failed

Tags: apex, class, unit-test

Someone else created a class and test class that works fine: 
CRequestForm_SearchController and CRequestForm_SearchController_test.

I made some edits to the class in sandbox, and copied the test class, so now I have a new class and a new test class: TESTCRequestForm_SearchController and TESTCRequestForm_SearchController_test. But I can't push it to production because the code coverage is only 68%. I have manually tested it as an end-user and it works fine. Can anyone please help?

The exception thrown is:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object, stack trace is Class.TESTCRequestForm_SearchController_Test.constructor_Test: line 29, column 1

### UPDATE: I also posted this on developer.salesforce, and someone pointed out a very obvious error:

Few changes in the testclass should help you in getting the code coverage issues. First of all, you need to insert data in SFDC_IDs__c custom setting as org's data is not available in testclass by default.So,

```
1   SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDs = SFDC_IDs__c.getValues('SSAI');
2   Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;
```

should be replaced by something like this:

```
1   SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDsRecord =  new SFDC_IDs__c();
2   SSAIIDsRecord.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c = 'Id of system administrator profile in your org';
3   insert SSAIIDsRecord;
4    
5   SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDs = SFDC_IDs__c.getValues('SSAI');
6    Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;
```

and also replace

```
1   ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(newRec1);
2   CRequestForm_SearchController WrapperC=new CRequestForm_SearchController(controller);
```

with

```
> 1 ApexPages.StandardController controller = new
> ApexPages.StandardController(newRec1);
> 2 TESTCRequestForm_SearchController WrapperC=new
> TESTCRequestForm_SearchController(controller);
```

But then I have a new error: 
`Class.TESTCRequestForm_SearchController_Test.constructor_Test: line 30, column 1.` 
This is the code at line 30 :

```
insert SSAIIDsRecord;



System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]
```

This is my updated test class:

```
@isTest
private class TESTCRequestForm_SearchController_Test {

    static testmethod void constructor_Test() {
        Test.startTest();

        SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDsRecord =  new SFDC_IDs__c();
        SSAIIDsRecord.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c = '00eA0000000O8c8IAC';
        insert SSAIIDsRecord;

        SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDs = SFDC_IDs__c.getValues('SSAI');
        Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.CRequestNew;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        User sau =
          [select UserRoleId
              from User
              where ProfileId = :saProfileId
               and isActive = true
               limit 1];

        System.runAs(sau) {       

        Account newAcc=new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert newAcc;

        Contact_Request_Form__c newRec1 =new  Contact_Request_Form__c(Last_Name__c='Last Name Test',First_Name__c='First Name Test',Email_Address__c='TEST2@MAIL.COM',Status__c='Submitted');
        newRec1.Subgrantee_Name__c=newAcc.Id;
        insert newRec1;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', newRec1.Id);

        Contact newContact=new Contact();
        newContact.LastName='Last Name';
        newContact.FirstName='First Name';
        newContact.AccountId=newAcc.Id;
        insert newContact;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', newContact.Id);

        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(newRec1);
        TESTCRequestForm_SearchController WrapperC=new TESTCRequestForm_SearchController(controller);

        WrapperC.setuserinput3('T');
        WrapperC.contactsearch();

        pageRef = WrapperC.createCRequestNew();

        System.assertNotEquals(pageRef, null);

        pageRef = WrapperC.createCRequest();
        System.assertEquals(pageRef, null);
        pageRef = WrapperC.createCRequestDelete();
        pageRef = WrapperC.createCDelete();
        pageRef = WrapperC.createCModify();
        System.assertNotEquals(pageRef, null);
         }    
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

---

```
public with sharing class TESTCRequestForm_SearchController {

    public TESTCRequestForm_SearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        cid=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        }

    Public String cid;                                                           
    public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}                                
    public boolean errormsg=false;
    public String errorDetail='';                                               
    String userinput1;                                                            
    String userinput2;
    String userinput3;                                                              

    Public boolean displayboxes;
    Public List<Contact> results = new List<Contact>();                                    

    Public List<Contact> selectedContactsstep2 = new List<Contact>();            
    Public List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();

    public String getuserinput1(){
        return userinput1;
        }

    public void setuserinput1(String userinp){
        this.userinput1=userinp;
        }

    public String getuserinput2(){
        return userinput2;
        }

    public void setuserinput2(String userinp){
        this.userinput2=userinp;
        }

    public String getuserinput3(){
        return userinput3;
        }

    public void setuserinput3(String userinp){
        this.userinput3=userinp;
        }
    public String geterrorDetail()
    {
        return errorDetail;
    } 



    public List<Contact> contactsearch(){    
        errormsg=false;    
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        if(userinput1=='' && userinput2=='' && userinput3=='')
        {
        errormsg=true;
        errorDetail='Please enter atleast one field to search for matching contact';
        contactList=null;
        return null;
        }   
        for(Contact c : [select Account.Name,Name,FirstName,LastName,Email,title,Id from Contact where FirstName like :userinput1+'%' and LastName like :userinput2+'%' and Account.Name like :userinput3+'%'])    
        {       
        contactList.add(new cContact(c));    
        }
        return null;
        }

    public List<cContact> getresults()
    {
        return contactList;
    }

    public class cContact{
        public Contact con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public cContact(Contact c) {    
        con = c;    
        selected = false;
        }
    }


    public boolean geterrormsg()
    {
        return errormsg;
    }


    public Pagereference createCRequestNew()
    {       
        Pagereference p =new Pagereference('/apex/CRequestNew');

        return p;
    }       

    public Pagereference createCRequest()
    {
        List<Contact> selectedContact = new List<Contact>();
        Pagereference p =new Pagereference('/a02/o'); 
        if (contactList!= null)  {    

                for (cContact similarContact : contactList) {
                    if (similarContact.selected==true) {
                        selectedContact.add(similarContact.con);
                    }
            }
        if (selectedContact.size()==0) {    
        errormsg=true;
        errorDetail='Please select a contact to Modify';    
        return null;
        }
        else {    
        errormsg=false;
        String idField='';
        for (Contact selectedCont : selectedContact) {
        idField=selectedCont.Id;     
        }    
        p =new Pagereference('/apex/TEST_CRequestModify'+'?cid='+idField);    
        return p;
        }       

    }
    return p;
    }
    public Pagereference createCRequestDelete()
    {
            List<Contact> selectedContact = new List<Contact>();
        Pagereference p =new Pagereference('/a02/o'); 
        if (contactList!= null)  {    

                for (cContact similarContact : contactList) {
                    if (similarContact.selected==true) {
                        selectedContact.add(similarContact.con);
                    }
            }
        if (selectedContact.size()==0) {    
        errormsg=true;
        errorDetail='Please select a contact to Delete';    
        return null;
        }
        else {    
        errormsg=false;
        String idField='';
        for (Contact selectedCont : selectedContact) {
        idField=selectedCont.Id;     
        }    
        p =new Pagereference('/apex/TEST_Delete_contact_CRF'+'?cid='+idField);    
        return p;
        }       

    }
    return p;


    }

    public Contact_Request_Form__c NewCRequest(Contact cContact)
        {

        Contact_Request_Form__c  c = new Contact_Request_Form__c();
            c.Subgrantee_Name__c   =cContact.AccountId;          
            c.Last_Name__c      =cContact.LastName ;
        c.First_Name__c    =cContact.FirstName ;
        c.MI__c         =cContact.MI__c ;

        c.Fax_Phone__c     =cContact.Fax ;
        c.Mobile_Phone__c    =cContact.MobilePhone;
        c.Home_Phone__c     =cContact.HomePhone ;
        c.Business_Phone__c   =cContact.OtherPhone ;

        c.Email_Address__c   =cContact.Email ;
        c.Job_Title__c     =cContact.Title;
        c.Department_B__c     =cContact.Department;
        c.Department_S__c     =cContact.Shipping_Department__c;

        c.Organization_S__c   =cContact.Shipping_Organization__c;
        c.Organization_B__c   =cContact.Mailing_Organization__c;


        c.Address_Line_1B__c   =cContact.Contact_Mailing_Street_1__c; 
        c.Address_Line_2B__c   =cContact.Contact_Mailing_Street_2__c ;
        c.City_B__c       =cContact.Contact_Mailing_City__c ;
        c.Zip_Code_B__c     =cContact.Contact_Mailing_Zip_Code__c ;
        c.Business_State__c   =cContact.Contact_Mailing_State__c  ;

        c.SSAI_Fiscal__c    =cContact.SSAI_Fiscals__c  ;
        c.SSAI_Spon__c     =cContact.SSAI_Sponsors__c  ;
        c.SSAI_Directors__c   =cContact.SSAI_Directors__c  ;
        c.D2D_Contacts__c     =cContact.D2D_Contacts__c  ;

        c.Address_Line_1S__c   =cContact.Contact_Shipping_Street_1__c; 
        c.Address_Line_2S__c   =cContact.Contact_Shipping_Street_2__c ;
        c.City_S__c       =cContact.Contact_Shipping_City__c  ;
        c.Zip_Code_S__c     =cContact.Contact_Shipping_Zip_Code__c; 
        c.Shipping_State__c   =cContact.Contact_Shipping_State__c  ;

        //c.Fax_Phone__c      =cContact.Contact_Fax__c  ;
        c.Fax_Phone__c     =cContact.Fax  ;
        c.Contact__c     =cContact.Id;


        return c;


        }
        public Pagereference createCModify()
    {
    errormsg=false;
    String idField='';
    idField=cid;     
    Pagereference p =new Pagereference('/apex/CRequestModify'+'?cid='+idField);    
    return p;
    }

    public Pagereference createCDelete()
    {
        Pagereference p =new Pagereference('/a02/o');      
        errormsg=false;
        Contact cContact=[Select Id,LastName,FirstName,MI__c,Fax,MobilePhone,HomePhone,OtherPhone,Email,Title,Contact_Mailing_Street_2__c
                            ,Contact_Mailing_City__c ,Contact_Mailing_Zip_Code__c ,SSAI_Sponsors__c,SSAI_Directors__c,Department,Contact_Mailing_Street_1__c ,
                            SSAI_Fiscals__c,D2D_Contacts__c,Contact_Shipping_Street_1__c ,Contact_Shipping_Street_2__c ,Contact_Shipping_City__c ,
                            Contact_Shipping_Zip_Code__c ,Contact_Fax__c ,Contact_Mailing_State__c ,Contact_Shipping_State__c,Shipping_Organization__c,
                            Mailing_Organization__c,Shipping_Department__c,AccountId from Contact where id =:cid limit 1];
            Contact_Request_Form__c newRec =NewCRequest(cContact);
            newRec.Status__c='Submitted';
            newRec.Is_Delete_Request__c=true;
        insert newRec;          
        return p;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked through the developer console to see which parts of the code are not covered by your test ? Without that as a start, this is going to somewhat challenging to help you on.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke : the method is constructor_Test, and the error is System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object, stack trace is Class.TESTCRequestForm_SearchController_Test.constructor_Test: line 29, column 1

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I am just an admin and not a developer, so if there's any information that I left out, please let me know. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: In the original class, when you click delete, a delete record is automatically submitted. I created a new VF page to allow user to enter more information and then submit the delete record. The only change I made is in public Pagereference createCRequestDelete(), which reference p =new Pagereference('/apex/ **TEST_Delete_contact_CRF'** +'?cid='+idField);

Comment: @LongTruong what is the code that is at line 29 in this failing test class?

Comment: @markpond : it's this line :Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;

Comment: I think it's trying to log in as a system admin and create new contact request form

Comment: You can use system.debug() to put more specific debug info into the log.  Using "if ( null == SSAIIDs){ system.debug ('Admin Profile is null'); }", will let you know if that variable is getting initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me the solution!!! 
replace

```
 SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDsRecord =  new SFDC_IDs__c();
    SSAIIDsRecord.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c = '00eA0000000O8c8IAC';
    insert SSAIIDsRecord;

    SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDs = SFDC_IDs__c.getValues('SSAI');
    Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;
```

with this:

```
SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDsRecord =  new SFDC_IDs__c();
**SSAIIDsRecord.Name = 'SSAI';**
SSAIIDsRecord.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c = 'Id of system administrator profile in your org';
insert SSAIIDsRecord;

SFDC_IDs__c SSAIIDs = SFDC_IDs__c.getValues('SSAI');
 Id saProfileId = SSAIIDs.System_Administrator_Profile_ID__c;
```